# Google Cloud Remote API cannot deserialize remote error from Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, remoteapi

I'm connected locally to a remote Google Cloud Datastore using the Google's [RemoteApiInstaller](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiInstaller)

When trying to save an entity into the Datastore I'm getting the error: `com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: remote API call: can't deserialize server-side exception`

Does anyone know how I can see the server side exception either through Datastore logs or by figuring out how to deserialize the error?

Comment: Is there a cause attached to the exception? The other place to check would be the your application logs in the Cloud Platform Console (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/#reading_logs_in_the_console).

Comment: @EdDavisson It's being caused by the `save` function. Does datastore write logs? My application is running locally not on appeninge

Comment: The Remote API works by talking to a remote App Engine App that has a special piece of code deployed to proxy the API calls. So if the failure is happening on the server side, there may be application logs there.

Comment: @EdDavisson Good point. Ok so this is the error I found in the logs, any idea where I can lookup what this code means? `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10001: `